# WCF Security: What is best for intranet with mostly java clients?

Tags: wcf, security

The data is not sensitive, I am really only considering security so that I can keep track of who is calling our system.

I thought of just having each 'client' send an 'api-key' in the request and cross-check against a list of valid keys.

I could then log the request and monitor activity by client.

Note: performance is very critical so I can't afford alot of overhead.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

HTTP's Basic auth is fairly lightweight and it can be used for both RESTful service and SOAP. See [Basic Authentication with WCF REST service to something other than windows accounts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660445/) for details.